# Bug in RepeatedNull?

Tags: pattern-matching, bugs

`RepeatedNull` appears to be buggy (versions 8.0, and 9.0).

Define `f` as follows:

```
In[1]:= f@s:{h_@___...} := List @@@ s
```

`f` is intended to accept (possibly empty) List of non-atomic (possibly empty) expressions with the same head and change that head to List. It seems to work properly at first:

```
In[2]:= f@{g[x], g[y]}
Out[2]= {{x}, {y}}
```

(Calculates as intended.)

```
In[3]:= f@{g[x], h[y]}
Out[3]= f[{g[x], h[y]}]
```

(Pattern does not match.)

However, `f` behaves unexpectedly on an empty List:

```
In[4]:= f@{}
Out[4]= {1}
```

The pattern does match, as it should, but the appearance of `1` is a complete mystery. I expected `f@{}` to be `List @@@ {}`, which is `{}`. Tracing didn't tell me anything:

```
In[5]:= Trace[f@{}, TraceInternal -> True]
Out[5]= {f[{}], List@@{1}, {1}}
```

It's probably a bug. Defining `f@{}` as a special case seems to fix the problem. However, 1) it's not actually a special case, and 2) I'm not sure in the correctness of the definition since there may be something wrong with the pattern I picked.

1. Was `{h_@___...}` the right choice of pattern for “(possibly empty) List of non-atomic (possibly empty) expressions with the same head”?
2. Is there a plausible explanation where does `1` come from?

**UPD:**

To clear things up I'll elaborate on a test example by @m_goldberg (from the answer) and a note by @sebhofer (from a comment):

```
In[6]:= ReleaseHold[ClearAll /@ Hold[test1, test2]];
In[7]:= test1[patt1: {h_@___ ...}] := Row@{"With named head: ", patt1}
        test2[patt2: {_@___ ...}] := Row@{"Without named head: ", patt2}
```

Results vary with use of named vs unnamed pattern. That's one aspect convincing me to calssify the issue as bug:

```
In[9]:= {test1@{}, test2@{}} // Column
Out[9]= "With named head:" 
        "Without named head:" {}
```

(Here and after, output formatting is adjusted manually.)

What also concerns me is that existing definitions don't get overwritten:

```
In[10]:= ClearAll@test
In[11]:= test[patt1 : {h_@___ ...}] := Row@{"With named head: ", patt1}
         test[patt2 : {_@___ ...}] := Row@{"Without named head: ", patt2}
         DownValues@test
Out[13]= {HoldPattern[test[patt2:{_[___]...}]]  :> "Without named head:" patt2,
          HoldPattern[test[patt1:{h_[___]...}]] :> "With named head:" patt1}
In[14]:= test@{}
Out[14]= "Without named head:" {}
```

`DownValues` is prepended with the subsequent ones:

```
In[15]:= test[patt1 : {h_@___ ...}] := Row@{"Newdef, with named head: ", patt1}
         test[patt2 : {_@___ ...}] := Row@{"Newdef, without named head: ", patt2}
         DownValues@test
Out[17]= {HoldPattern[test[patt2:{_[___]...}]]  :> "Newdef, without named head:" patt2,
          HoldPattern[test[patt1:{h_[___]...}]] :> "Newdef, with named head:" patt1,
          HoldPattern[test[patt2:{_[___]...}]]  :> "Without named head:" patt2,
          HoldPattern[test[patt1:{h_[___]...}]] :> "With named head:" patt1}
In[18]:= test@{}
Out[18]= "Newdef, without named head:" {}
```

While output satisfactorily corresponds to new definition, this probably should not happen due to 1) unpredictability; 2) garbage accumulation.

(Additional examples of unstable pattern matching with `RepeatedNull` may be found in comments.)

Comment: That's not a problem with the pattern. Try `List @@@ Sequence[]`

Comment: Hint: What do you expect for `Apply[List, Sequence[], {1}]`? This is what your `List @@@ s` boils down to, when `s` is possibly "nothing".

Comment: @sebhofer Please post that as an answer. That is exactly what's going on here.

Comment: @rm-rf Can do, I thought we might want to keep the OP puzzling for a bit :)

Comment: @sebhofer Well, I'm still puzzled. :-) s must always be a List, right?

Comment: Oh, now I know what you are saying... sorry for that! Now I'm puzzled myself :)

Comment: Just an observation: `f[s : {_[___] ...}]` works in the "special case", but does not do what you want in general...

Comment: Ok, I vote for bug. Smallest example `{} /. s : {h_ ...} :> s` gives `Sequence[]`

Comment: @Rojo No señor. That is no bug. It is just a pecularity of RepeatedNull `MatchQ[ {Sequence[]}, {_ ...}]` giving `True` is completely fine. And `MatchQ[{}, { {} ...}]` giving `True` is also fine. Thus, `ff@{}` behaves as expected.

Comment: @Rojo, good example. Interesting that both `{} /. s : {h ...} :> s` and `{} /. s : {_ ...} :> s` behave as expected

Comment: @Rolf I am not completely sure but it looks like a peculiarity of `MatchQ` having no `HoldFirst` attribute. So in your example `MatchQ[{Sequence[]}, {_ ...}]` is exactly equivalent to `MatchQ[{}, {_ ...}]` as you can easily see with `Trace[MatchQ[{Sequence[]}, {_ ...}]]`.

Comment: @Simon And `{} /. s : {_h ...} :> s` behaves as expected too.

Comment: @RolfMertig The bug woundn't that it matches, but what the label `s` matches to

Comment: Not limited to V8. I confirm it is present in V9

Comment: Hm.. Am I missing something? Why can't I catch a `Sequence` produced in this/a similar way inside a `HoldComplete`, even though I can catch it inside `Print`? Compare `{} /. {h___} :> Print@Unevaluated[h]` and `{} /. {h___} :> Print@HoldComplete@Unevaluated[h]`. See also chat

Comment: There is also weirdness for `Replace` and the second argument of `Pattern` does not have to be `Blank[]` to have crazyness. For example `Replace[{}, s : {(h : bla) ...} :> s]` also gives `Sequence[]`

Comment: This bug also exists in version 7.  Good discovery!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is some evidence concerning what is going wrong.

```
ff[arg : {(h : _)@___ ...}] := Row @ {h, " : ", arg}

ff @ {u[x]}
```

> ```
> u : {u[x]}
> ```

```
ff @ {{x}}
```

> ```
> List : {{x}}
> ```

```
ff @ {{}}
```

> ```
> List : {{}}
> ```

All the above show what one would expect, but

```
ff @ {}
```

> ```
> {} :
> ```

In this last case, I conclude that `h` has been matched with `{}` and `arg` has been matched with `Sequence[]`. I can not but think that this is a bug.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your last phrase. If `arg` had been matched with `{}` and `h` with `Sequence[]` everything would be fine. But it was the other way around, and that's the bug.

Comment: @Rojo. Good catch, I corrected my typo.