# List comprehension in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request, python

Python supports a concept called "[list comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension)".

Following is sample example (written in *Python* syntax)

```python
A = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
print( [ a + [i]  for a in A for i in range(1, 4) if i in a] )
```

> ```
> [[1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4, 2], [2, 3, 4, 3], [3, 4, 5, 3]]
> ```

What's the most natural way to translate this *Python* code to *Mathematica*?
I have the following method:

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}};
Select[Table[ a ~ Join ~ {i}, {a, A}, {i, 3}] ~ Flatten ~ 1,
       MemberQ[ Most @ #, Last @ #]&]
```

but I think it's neither fast nor elegant, therefore I am looking for a better way.

Comment: The same article you linked has a few lines about Mathematica too.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/838/functional-style-using-lazy-lists)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This one is very close to your Python code

```
Join @@ Table[Append[a, i], {a, A}, {i, Intersection[Range[3], a]}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 2}, {2, 3, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 3}}
> ```

Comment: After I overviewed this answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/838/functional-style-using-lazy-lists), I acknowledged Mathematica's potential to build new styles -- instead of using array structures we could define {a,A} to be "for a in A" and "... if a in A" could be just the intersection. I think we could extend your answer here to create a visually-accessible Pythonic style to Mathematica. What do you think?

Comment: This assumes that one can compute the set of valid `a` ahead of time, and then to implement some way to do that computation before performing the operation. A list comprehension is far more general.

Answer (score 8):

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}};
Join @@ Table[If[a~MemberQ~i, a~Join~{i}, Unevaluated[]], {a, A}, {i, 3}]
Join @@ Table[a~Join~{i}, {a, A}, {i, Select[Range@3, a~MemberQ~# &]}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 2}, {2, 3, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 3}}

Comment: +1 for writing `Unevaluated[]` instead of `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]`, or `##&[]` :)

Comment: @Jacob What's wrong with my "vanishing function" `##&[]`?  (+1, by the way)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard haha nothing really, in fact I was glad to show off that I knew about it :P. But also despite all the talk about this, I may have missed the option of just using `Unevaluated[]`, so I guess I learned something :).

Comment: @Jacob I attempted to cover that in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/121) but I guess I should have been more explicit.  I said that "All of these heads meet this requirement:" and listed `Unevaluated` and `## &` -- both would be used the same way: `Unevaluated[]` and `## &[]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that one is a nice answer (as I suppose you can tell by the badge :P). I'm not very focussed right now, but perhaps an additional point of confusion could by that neither `Apply[]` nor `Symbol[]` evaluate to `Sequence[]` (anymore?).

Comment: @Jacob I'm not very good at explaining this I guess.  The parentheticals followed by the example were intended to clarify that, but I see now it is confusing.  I meant that after setting `seq = Sequence[]` you can use `seq`.  I'll try to think of a more clear yet concise way to say that and update my post.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard think nothing of it :). So long as you do not use `{} /. l : {h_ ...} :> l` to get `Sequence[]` ([link in case you missed it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36850/4330), I also have an unanswered comment there), I will gladly keep showing off my knowledge of your posts :P. By the by, just in case I deleted my previous temporary message before you saw it, I was hoping [this answer of mine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37961/4330) might interest you. I hope to write more answers similar to this one in the future (using compiled stuff/C) (temporary message)

Answer (score 7):

Some of the other approaches might be much more efficient, but the following shows how one can create something which is probably as easy to read (if one is fluent in Mathematica) as a python list comprehension:

```
SetAttributes[listComprehend, HoldAll]

listComprehend[Verbatim[Condition][body_, crit_],iters:({_, __}..)] := Flatten[
    Table[
        If[crit, body, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]],
        iterators
    ], 1]
```

use it like this:

```
listComprehend[Append[a, i] /; MemberQ[a, i], {a, A}, {i, 3}]
```

`/;` is the shortcut for `Condition` and usually can be read as "provided that" in mathematica code. Doing so, the above seems to be relatively clear code. Unfortunately the translation to one of the potentially more efficient approaches is not that simple...

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure if you're after the functionality, the way to generate your list, or some performance improvement. Anyway:

```
Cases[Outer[Join, A, List /@ Range@Length @A, 1], {___, x_, ___, x_}, 2]
(*
 {{1, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3}, 
  {2, 3, 4, 2}, {2, 3, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 3}}
*)
```

**Edit**

For efficiency, you may want to generate only the final elements, without the need to post filter them:

```
Flatten[Function[{u}, Table[Join[u, {i}], {i, u}]][#] & /@ A, 1]
```

or:

```
Flatten[Function[{u}, ReplaceList[#, Thread[x_ :> Flatten[{x, #}] & /@ u]]][#] & /@ A, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for a *literal* translation from *Python* to *Mathematica*, I think that something like the following snippet should do the trick:

```
Part[
 Reap@Do[
    Do[
     If[
      MemberQ[a, r],
       Sow@Flatten[{a, r}]
      ], {r, R}], {a, A}], 2, 1]
```

where `A = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}}` and `R=Range[1,3]` (note how in *Python* $list(range(1, 4))=[1, 2, 3]$)

Nevertheless, this question is about finding "*...the most natural way to translate this Python code to Mathematica*" and *[my view](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135736/python-numpy-array-manipulation-in-mathematica-syntax/154451#154451)* is that going for the literal translation is not always the best option (although it could very possibly be what you *need* at a certain point in time).

The answers to this question provide useful examples of how versatile *Mathematica* is.

Another *natural* way to achieve the intended result, is to use `Map`:

```
Flatten[
  Map[(
    a = #;
    Flatten[{a, #}] & /@ Pick[R, MemberQ[a, #] & /@ R]
   ) &, A], 1]
```

Perhaps, a more concise way to achieve the same result is the following:

```
f[a_, r_] := If[MemberQ[a, r], Flatten[{a, r}]]

Cases[
  Flatten[
    Outer[f, A, R, 1], 1], Except[Null], 1]
```

I think that this way is more close in practice to what the list comprehension does: it traverses the items of `A` (rows) and then it traverses the items in the range until it finds a match.Then it appends the range item to the list row and proceeds to the next row.