# Python/Numpy array manipulation in Mathematica syntax

Tags: list-manipulation, python

As a python programmer, numpy tools usually come to my mind if I want to manipulate arrays (list, matrices, ...). Is there any reference (e.g., dictionary) of how to translate numpy syntax to Mathematica syntax? For instance, assuming `a` is an array, I found the following translations (python code as quotes, Mathematica code as code):

- linspace / logspace

> a = np.linspace(0,10,11)

```
a = Array[# &, 11, {0, 10}]
(* {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

- element selection based on condition

> a[a>0]

```
Select[a, # > 0 &]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

- element selection based on other boolean array

> s = a>0
>
> a[s]

```
s = # > 0 & /@ a
Pick[a, s]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

- slicing

> a[3:-2:2]

```
a[[4;;-3;;2]]
(* {3, 5, 7} *)
```

Such a correspondence list is what I am looking for. Does this already exist? If not, I believe it would be helpful to extend this Q&A post to continuously build such a list.

One thing I am trying to use just now is `np.roll`. Using the example from above, I am searching for a command that yields

```
EquivalentOfNpRoll[a,2]
(* {9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

How would I do this? `Permute` seems to be an overkill. At least it was far from obvious to me how to implement this rolling permutation in a general but compact way.

**Update:**

From the comments:

> np.roll(a,2)

```
RotateRight[a, 2]
(* {9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} *)
```

> a=np.arange(0,11,1)

```
a = Range[0, 10, 1]
```

Comment: You're looking for `RotateRight[]` and `RotateLeft[]` in the last question, I think.

Comment: Yes, indeed, `RotateRight[]` seems to be the equivalent of `np.roll()`, thanks. I am still interested in a "dictionary" for python/numpy users on the topic of list manipulations.

Comment: That's fine, but I don't know numpy & its array functions, so someone else will have to help.  With a specific example, I can guess. :)

Comment: Have tried googling? I could be wrong, but I doubt the majority of Mathematica users have Python backgrounds, so I don't think there has been much motivation to create the kind document you are looking for.

Comment: I have googled for such a dictionary and for a number of specific commands, including those examples in my question. I thought instead of posting a question related to every single correspondence it would make sense to bundle it in one question. Maybe I'm wrong and this is out of scope here, I'm not sure.

Comment: Another Mathematica hint: `a = Range[0, 11]` is much simpler and quicker.

Comment: See [here](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/).

Comment: I have just started learning Python. I would be, therefore, interested in such a dictionary, but another way around: from Wolfram to Python. Please keep me informed.

Comment: I think the most direct equivalent to np.linspace would be [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide).

Comment: These guides have the information OP is looking for: ["Handling Arrays Of Data"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/HandlingArraysOfData.html) , ["List Manipulation"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html). (Lots of point-and-click operations have to be used.)

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Generally speaking, Python sucks. I avoid it as much as I can. Unfortunately, almost anyone I work with who is under 35 and claiming to be a data scientist uses Python... Interestingly, I was inclined to make a dictionary like that for R <-> Mathematica, but I after I learned R to a point, I decided it is not worth the effort. (Granted Mathematica and R are fairly similar within the realm of programming languages.)

Answer (score 4):

I think that both *Python* and *Mathematica* are great programming languages. They provide a lot of built-in 'stuff' to work with as a beginner and allow you to grow along with the language itself. My experience with *Mathematica* is definitely greater than what I have with *Python* so I would never claim this answer as definitive.

Having said that, I will have to note that any aspiring programmer that wants to migrate from *Python* to *Mathematica* would not be better-off by using a 'cook book' or 'dictionary' approach.

I can understand the appeal in the cook-book approach (I ***have*** sought for it myself on different occasions). It provides a quick solution for the (any) problem at hand and it also allows one to build a progressive understanding of the target language.

I don't think there's anything wrong with having 'quick solutions' available per se neither is 'progressively' moving towards a goal a bad thing. The problem I see in using a dictionary to translate from one language to another is, simply, that meaning is something more than syntax. In the context of translating *Python* to *Mathematica*, you might get an easy way out but that might not play out for you in the end because of what would be missing.

As a more concrete example I will use the case of *Python*'s (*NumPy*'s) *[linspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)*. Scrolling  down to the examples,

*np.linspace(2.0, 3.0, num=5)*

can be translated in *Mathematica* as `Array[# &, 5, {2, 3}]`. This is an accurate translation and it's useful for some things but not for others.

Someone using the dictionary, would not know that the output of `Array` as used, is a mix of *rationals* and *integers*. Now, that might not sound as a huge problem for someone wanting to achieve a rough first translation. But it could be a problem for another person.

Also, you could achieve the same result when using `Table[i, {i, 2, 3, 0.25}]`. Only this time, the results are *real* numbers.

And there are issues of 'efficiency'. Supposedly, `Array` is faster than `Table` and I think that this has to do with the fact that the later uses indexing.

I haven't even scratched the surface of the issue, but that was not my intention. I understand the need for having fast solutions. I don't think that it pays in the long-run to switch from *Python* to *Mathematica* that way. I understand it's uncomfortable (I have experienced it and I still experience it with *Python*), but to me it seems that the best way to migrate to a language is to actually use it.